# How to configure a Trackpad to connect automatically to two different Macs?

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

I have a private Trackpad, which I use at work also. I want that the Trackpad connect itself automatically to both computers.

If I use the Trackpad only on one Mac it connects itself automatically (on power on), but since I connected it to my Work-Macbook I have to connect it every time I change the Mac manually!

Is it possible to configure the Trackpad to autoconnect to both Macs?

### Edit

It's a bluetooth trackpad and the internal memory is empty... where can I configure the double-connections, or find out if it could connect to both Macs?

Comment: What's a "private track pad"?

Comment: just a normal trackpad, but my own ;) not from work... not important for the issue, but for the story ;)

Comment: Who makes the trackpad?  Do you connect via a USB receiver on your laptop?

Comment: This is the "big" apple-Trackpad .. Model A1535 .. I connect via bluetooth

Answer (score 2):

Unless your device can handle multiple connections, the answer is no.

Whether it's a Bluetooth track pad or one with a receiver (like Logitech unifying receiver), you can only have as many connections as the "memory" in the device will allow.  Most mice/keyboards/track pads are 1:1 devices.